# How to strtok in C twice?

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to parse spaces and then commas for a project the data is similar to this:

```
37,4 23,4,9,6 22,11 99,29
```

I want to first split them with spaces and then split the commas to get individual numbers.
But this doesn't work.

```
char *token = strtok(singleLine, " ");

while( token != NULL ) {
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    char *token2 = strtok(token, ",");
    while(*token2 != NULL){
        printf("%s", token)
        token2 = strtok(NULL,",");
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you declaring `singleLine`?

Comment: The code you posted has two compile errors in it.

Comment: fgets(singleLine, 5000, inputPointer);
singleLine is something I get from a file. Its just the data I put in the description

Comment: `while(*token2 != NULL) { printf("%s", token) ...` ==> `while(token2 != NULL) { printf("%s ", token2) ...` (three corrections).

Answer (score 1):

The `strtok` function uses an internal static variable to keep track of its state, so if you attempt to interleave processing of two different strings / substrings the internal state gets corrupted.

If your system supports it, you should instead use `strtok_r` (or `strok_s` on Windows)  This function takes an additional parameter to keep track of its current state.

```
char *state_inner, *state_outer;
char *token = strtok_r(singleLine, " ", &state_outer);

while (token != NULL ) {
    token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &state_outer);
    char *token2 = strtok_r(token, ",", &state_inner);
    while (token2 != NULL){
        printf("%s", token);
        token2 = strtok_r(NULL,",", &state_inner);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to compile and run the project on some school zeus VPN thing. I will check if I can use strtok_r, when I use in on my local it gives me that implicit function declaration error.

Comment: @Vehbi `strtok_r` should be available on Linux.  If you're using MSVC (i.e. Windows) the equivalent function is `strtok_s`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't "nest" calls to `strtok` like that - you'll have split into the string `"37,4 23,4,9,6 22,11 99,29"` into the sequence `"37,4"`, `"23,4,9,6"`, `"22,11"`, `"99,29"` *and then* split each of those tokens to get the individual numbers.